# Hibernate mapping - Two tables with same column referencing to one table with foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, mapping

I have three tables in MySql, one of them is Message table and other ones are advert tables as below screenshot: 
[image]
Each advert will contain messages. I've tried to map this in Hibernate as below:
[image]
but naturally, it gives error for the repeated column mapping. What are your suggestions about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the 2 advert tables in one table and distguish between them by type 'income' or 'outcome'

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be different columns in these tables, so It's impossible to make one table

Comment: You can use the heritage in hibernate . These 2 tables can reference to a super table